# How do I pass arguments to pkill, over ssh, through java's ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, ssh, processbuilder

I am trying to kill a process, remotely, through the java interface to the shell, using ProcessBuilder.  My code looks like this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( 
  "ssh", 
  "user@host", 
  "pkill -f \"'instanceId XXXXXX'\"");
Process process = builder.start();
```

Where instanceId XXXXX matches some command line args from the launching of the process.

When I get the final command string, using

```
builder.command()
```

it returns

```
ssh user@host pkill -f "'instanceId XXXXX'"
```

which, when run manually on the command line works.  Unfortunately, when run by the ProcessBuilder, it is incapable of identifying the target process.

After spending far too many hours fighting with arguments over ssh/ProcessBuilder in the last weeks, could someone shed some light on why it's doing this, and maybe point me at some relevant documentation that isn't completely cryptic?

Comment: Try it while removing the double quotes around the instanceID thing.

Comment: It leaves me a bit more confused.  Without the double quotes, it fails when run on the command line, but it works when run through the ProcessBuilder.

Comment: I thought the double quotes are required by pkill, otherwise it thinks it has two argument and complains.  At least that is how it behaves when executed directly on the command line.  Perhaps the way ProcessBuilder marshals the arguments uses another way of telling pkill there is only one argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the double quotes.

When you run the command on the command line, the shell will interpret either double or single quotes itself. Thus, if you run

```
ssh user@host pkill -f 'instanceId XXXXX'
```

(Or the same with double quotes) from command line, it will strip those quotes. Although the local shell considers the string `instanceID XXXX` as a single argument, the *remote* shell sees the command as a whole, doesn't see any quotes, and so sees "InstanceId" and "XXXXX" as two separate entities.

For this reason, *when you run from command line*, you need to add quotes over the quotes. The local shell will strip the external quotes, and ssh will pass the command with the internal quotes, which will cause the remote shell to see the  `instanceID XXXX` as a single parameter.

However, when you run from a process builder, you don't run from a local shell. You build the arguments yourself, appropriately, and they are sent *literally* to the ssh. Thus, when you send `"'InstanceID XXXX'"`, what the remote shell will see is `"'InstanceID XXXX'"`. It will only strip one pair, and `'InstanceID XXXX'` is not in any processes command line on the remote machine. Not with those quotes...

Thus, when you use a process builder, you should not be quoting the same way you quote when you run directly in the shell. Only a single pair is needed.

Comment: Okay, that explains it perfectly for my current level of nixiness.  Thanks a heap.  I thought ProcessBuilder was actually invoking the shell, and not the ssh command directly.  Again, thanks.

Comment: @DavidLawson Yes, it's important to understand that the command is executed *directly*, not through a shell. Thus, you can also not use shortened paths like `~/foo.txt`, or environment variables  like `$HOME/foo.txt`, or any shell builtin commands.